# uname shows duplicate architecture

Tags: command-line

Why does uname show x86_64 three times?  This is Ubuntu 12.04.4.

```
$ uname -a
Linux seedbox 3.2.0-59-generic #90-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 7 22:43:51 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Take a look at the man page for `uname` for basic questions such as this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `uname`, `uname -a` is short for `uname -snrvmpio`:

```
$ uname -snrvmpio
Linux name 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ for o (s n r v m p i o) {printf -$o:\ ; uname -$o}
-s: Linux
-n: name
-r: 3.11.0-12-generic
-v: #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013
-m: x86_64
-p: x86_64
-i: x86_64
-o: GNU/Linux
```

With `m`, `-p`, `-i` being:

> ```
> -m, --machine            print the machine hardware name
> -p, --processor          print the processor type or "unknown"
> -i, --hardware-platform  print the hardware platform or "unknown"
> ```

Comment: is there a possibility these three values could be different? I mean, if the processor is of x86_64 type, how can the other two be anything else?

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas, what's the difference between the machine hardware name and the hardware platform?